# how to send array data to api with alamofire?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, api, alamofire

this is my parameters send to api

```
let params : [String : Any]  = [
      "interests" : interestParams
]
```

and output of params is like this

```
[interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]
```

i need to send parameters like this

```
{ "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }
```

Comment: Hi @alex. it's hard without seeing your Actual code...

Comment: What difficult you are facing in this and add your tried code

Comment: my api return always  "must be a type of  array"

Comment: because my api need this { "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }

Comment: not like what i send [interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]

Comment: No, json `{ "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }` is not an array.

Comment: And Swift `[interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]` is not an array either.

Comment: let params : [String : Any]  = [
            "interests" : interestParams
        ]

        
        print(params)
        
        Alamofire.request(base_Url+"/interests", method: .patch, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (Response) in
            
            let responData : JSON = JSON(Response.result.value!)
            
            
            switch Response.result {
                
            case .success:
                print(responData)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

Comment: Try passing `[params]` instead.

Comment: how to make my params be an array ?

Comment: @alex  `{ "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }` and `[interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]` are same.. one is in json notation and other is in swift.

Comment: @matt `[params]` makes result `[[interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]]` and in json `[{ "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }]` so its totally wrong.

Comment: @dahiya_boy at least it’s an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it like this way all of the time Xcode will not print the json like you want

```
{ "interests": ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"] }
```

but in actutal it will send data in this form to server in the request.

So don't worry that Xcode is displaying like this

```
[interests : ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]]
```

Comment: oke , actually my backend do a little typo on their query . but thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can convert array to json string then you can pass this json string in a dictionary.

Convert array to json string by using this code.

```
 func json(from object:Any) -> String? {
    guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []) else {
        return nil
    }
    return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
  }

    let interestParams = ["Olahraga", "Sains", "Musik"]
    let jsonString = json(from: interestParams)
```

Pass this json string in dictionary like this.

```
    let params : [String : Any]  = [
        "interests" : jsonString as Any
    ]
```